# packaging protractor test script and the dependencies into one file

Tags: javascript, protractor, packaging

Now I make my protractor to work. Then I have another question: How to package the spec files and all the dependencies into one file, such as rpm or other format, so I can easily install it on another machine to run it? I searched the Internet and found some tools to package the javascript and CSS and images used in web page. But in my case, I only need to package the javascript I write to do the testing to one file.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that's not possible.

When you run protractor on a fresh machine you need to have

1. an instance of selenium-webdriver server running (with all the browsers you want to test)
2. nodejs

But, assuming that the new computer you run protractor in has nodejs and selenium-webdriver is set up (i.e. either the local computer has it running, or you're testing over network like using saucelabs), then I guess you can zip up the file to send as one file.

Comment: Thanks. then we zip it manually or we can build it using some tool?

Comment: Well, honestly I don't know why you would want to do this. Maybe you can explain your use case?

Comment: because we build it from gerrit and then run it on another machine. I am trying Maven Assembly Plugin now. hope it works.